# Error: "Type 'any' has no subscript members" in my Swift 3 project when I am retrieving info from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, types, firebase-realtime-database

This is giving me the type 'any' has no subscript members error. How can i fix this? Plz help fast!

Here is the code:

```
func loadData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("reports").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)  in
        let objName = snapshot.key
        print("key: \(objName)")
        let tit = snapshot.value!["title"] as! String // Error here
        let snip = snapshot.value!["snip"] as! String // Error here
        let lat = snapshot.value!["lat"] as! Double // Error here
        let long = snapshot.value!["long"] as! Double // Error here

        let marker = MKPointAnnotation()
        marker.title = tit
        marker.subtitle = snip
        marker.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(marker)

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

New code:

```
func loadData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("reports").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)  in
        let objName = snapshot.key
        print("key: \(objName)")
        let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let tit = dict?["title"] as? String
        let snip = dict?["snip"] as! String
        let lat = dict?["lat"] as! Double
        let long = dict?["long"] as! Double

        let marker = MKPointAnnotation()
        marker.title = tit
        marker.subtitle = snip
        marker.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(marker)

    })
}
```